# Convert "Only Believers respect God" to predicate logic.

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic, word-problem

> *Only Believers respect God*
>
> Convert the above given English statement to predicate logic.

---

I tried it as

$$B(x) = x~\textrm{ is a believer};~~ G(x) = x~\textrm{ respects God}\\ \exists~ x : ~(B(x)~ \land~ G(x))$$

---

Comment: "All B respect G" (the set of Believers is included into the set of God-respectful) does not exclude that some non-B also respect G, while with "Only B respect G" this is not possible (the set of God-respectful is included into the set of Believers).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OP's proposed solution is that there exists at least one believer, who also respects God.  This is  not equal to the original request, and indeed need not even be true.  For example, if nobody respects God, then the original is true but OP's solution is false.

A correct version, using the same predicates $B(x), G(x)$, is $$\forall x, (\neg B(x))\to (\neg G(x))$$

A simpler correct version is $$\forall x, G(x)\to B(x)$$

Comment: I am not completely sure: perhaps I'd translate the statement with a logical equivalence “⇔”. In the natural language sentence given I perceive a sense that all believers respect God, and all non-believers don't.

Comment: I agree : "$A$ only if $B$" is $A \to B$; thus we have to read the OP's sentence as : "$x$ respect God only if $x$ is a Believer" and thus : $\forall x (Gx \to Bx)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I thought like that only. One more modification that I think is "All those who respect God are believers". That's also giving the same thing.

Comment: @vadim123 Can you specify difference between "All believers respect God" and "Only believers respect God" ?

Comment: @Garrick, the former is $\forall x, B(x)\to G(x)$; the latter is what I have in my solution.

Answer (score 10):

Your attempt translates back into English as "there is someone who is a believer and respects God", which is not at all what you meant: this would be true if a billion nonbelievers respected God as long as one single believer did too.

To get a correct translation, think about this. First, an existential statement only talks about one person; you want a *universal* statement. Second, suppose $x $ respects God. What can you conclude about $x $?

Comment: Can you specify difference between "All believers respect God" and "Only believers respect God" ?

Comment: @Garrick "All believers respect God" is proven false by finding a believer who does not respect God. "Only believers respect God" is proven false by finding someone who is not a believer, but respects God anyway.

Answer (score 2):

¬∃x: ¬B(x) ∧ G(x)

If only believers respect God, then a person who's not a believe yet respects God can not exist.

UPDATE: regarding OP's question in comment, let me elaborate:

All believers respect God means there is no such believer that does not respect. 
¬∃x: B(x) ∧ ¬G(x) --> ∀x: ¬(B(x) ∧ ¬G(x)) --> ∀x: B(x) → G(x)
Meaning: if you're a believer, you respect God

If only believers respect God, then there's no such person that respects God while not being a believer.
¬∃x: ¬B(x) ∧ G(x) --> ∀x: G(x) → B(x)
Meaning: if you respect God, you must be a believer

Comment: Correct; but $¬∃x$ is $∀x¬$ and $¬(p ∧ q)$ is equiv to $p \to ¬q$. Thus $¬∃x(¬B(x) ∧ G(x))$ is equivalent to $∀x(¬B(x) \to ¬G(x))$ i.e. vadim's proposed translation.

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Comment: @AndrásHummer, Can you specify difference between "All believers respect God" and "Only believers respect God" ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the statement doesn't say that believers don't disrespect god as well. It says only they *can* respect god, but that doesn't mean they all do. You can alternatively pose logically from the alternative non-believer side. A non-believer can neither respect nor disrespect something they know not to exist. There is an ambiguity in the statement that needs to be expressed too. The other factor is that respect and disrespect is only perceived by the believing group.

Comment: There _are_ elements of the statement that are not easily expressed in predicate logic, such as what precisely it means to "respect" someone. But most of the objections expressed here seem insubstantial. You've shown that "disrespect" is not equivalent to "not respect," but "disrespect" is not used in the statement. Who perceives the statements is usually not a concern of predicate logic (otherwise very few statements indeed would translate). If nobody respects God because God does not exist, then the statement is true.